# Mechanics of making matza on Pesach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, matzah

When making matzah at home during the Pesach week, is it correct that one needs to ensure that not only is the matzah itself completed in 18 minutes, but also that all the utensils and bowls are completely cleaned so that no new chametz is created?

This seems particularly relevant for the making of "soft" (i.e., original) matzah, in that it doesn't keep.  For groups that eat soft matzah, (or, historically in any period in which soft matzah was eaten) do people make it throughout the Pesach holiday?  I am assuming that most families buy, rather than make, hard matzah.

Comment: See OC 458 and 459. Not only was baking Matza on Pesach widespread, it was considered a Mitzva to bake Matzot for the Seder on Erev Pesach afternoon.

Comment: Double AA, it would be great to turn your comment into an answer so that it could be marked as an answer and upvoted, rather than a comment.